# Sass change map key name

Tags: sass

Here is the varable and map:

```
$invert: true !default;

$example-map: (
  'default': (
    // value
  ),
  'inverse': (
    // value
  )
) !default;
```

How can change the map key name when `$invert == true`.

Like this:

```
@each $key, $value in $example-map {
  @if $invert {
    // change key name default to be inverse
    // change key name inverse to be default
  }
}
```

Or how can change the map key name in function method?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no "changing the key name", there's only setting the key to another value.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```css
@each $key, $value in $example-map {
  @if $invert {
        // change key name default to be inverse
        @if $key == default {$key : inverse;}
        // change key name inverse to be default
        @else if $key == inverse {$key : default;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?  Because this has a syntax error in it.  Answers need to definitively answer the question, not be a hint of things to try to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment i have just edited it and it works fine now